# Unable to run html suites in other browser except Firefox Using selenium RC

Tags: selenium-rc

I have problem in running test suites in other browser using selenium RC. 
I have a test suite which is exported from Selenium IDE. I am intending to run 5 tests in this suite. This suite runs and gives out correct results when *firefox is specified as browser.
It doesn't run the tests in any other browser.

**java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://www.global.com" "C:/Users/Desktop/PRP_RC/Article.html" 
"C:/Users/Desktop/PRP_RC/result.html"**

This is how I run the suite in command prompt.

When I use *iexplore(I use IE8) it throws an exception saying, Session Id 489504 doesn't exist
*iexploreproxy,*googlechrome and *safari will only open the respective browsers and display test case names on the browser. but doesn't run anything.

*piiexplore will open the browser and displays a script error. When i tried to debug the error, this is what is seen:

Webpage error details

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0;
>   iOpus-Web-Automation; SLCC2; .NET CLR
>   2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0;
>   .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) Timestamp: Wed, 9
>   Feb 2011 10:07:01 UTC
>
> Message: 'undefined' is null or not an
>   object Line: 476 Char: 9 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://www.global.com/selenium-server/core/scripts/selenium-testrunner.js

Comment: What version of Selenium RC are you running?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am having the same problem